# Infinite loop while reading yaml file because of pointers

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I'm reading and writing YML content into files. Some files are like that:

```yaml
&id001
playername: SomeName
lang: fr_FR
minerate-full-mined: *id001
```

The issue is that the `minerate-full-mined` key refer to the first line of file, so it make an infinite loop.

My code:

```java
DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
options.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new Representer(options) {
    {
        this.representers.put(Configuration.class, (data) -> represent(((Configuration) data).self));
    }
}, options);
```

```java
protected Map<String, Object> self;
protected Configuration defaults;
protected File file;

public Configuration() {
    this(null);
}

public Configuration(Configuration defaults) {
    this(null, new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>(), defaults);
}

public Configuration(File file, Map<?, ?> map, Configuration defaults) {
    this.file = file;
    this.self = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    this.defaults = defaults;
    for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String key = (entry.getKey() == null) ? "null" : entry.getKey().toString();
        if (entry.getValue() instanceof Map) {
            this.self.put(key, new Configuration(file, (Map<?, ?>) entry.getValue(), defaults == null ? null : defaults.getSection(key)));
        } else {
            this.self.put(key, entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

The infinite loop is made at the line `this.self.put(key, new Configuration[...]);`.

I tried to print `entry.getValue()`, and it's printed as `{playername: SomeName, lang: fr_FR, minerate-full-mined=(This Map)}`. So it can be detected, but I don't know that we can put a map on itself.

How can I prevent snakeyaml to take this in count ?

Comment: You can print the value because `toString()` contains a special check for the object itself, as described [here](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-4421469). However this only checks for direct self-references; if you were to have a cycle between two different maps this wouldn't work anymore, as described [here](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-6579224). Now for SnakeYAML, this is an *expected* feature because YAML caters to this problem. Thus I'd open an issue with SnakeYAML if this doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks @flyx . Should I simply use like `contains("(This map)"` or is there a way to check myself ? Also, is there a way to disable this feature from SnakeYAML ?

Comment: The feature is „properly serialize self-referential structures“. This feature is *expected* to be there in SnakeYAML, but apparently isn't implemented. From what I know of SnakeYAML's API, there isn't an option to enable it. You can check for self-references with recursive descent while storing the objects you have already visited in a map, though that doesn't help you writing the YAML, it only lets you recognize when you *would* run into an endless loop.

Comment: You can try to use SnakeYAML's `Composer` API to deserialize the YAML file to `Node`s which *might* be serializable again, though I don't know for sure. However then you can't access your data via your `Configuration` object so I'm unsure whether that's viable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a trick to skip it and prevent this type of issue, like that:

```
Configuration(File file, Map<?, ?> map, Configuration defaults) {
    this.file = file;
    this.self = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    this.defaults = defaults;
    for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String key = (entry.getKey() == null) ? "null" : entry.getKey().toString();
        if (entry.getValue() instanceof Map) {
            Configuration nextDef = defaults == null ? null : defaults.getSection(key);
            String checkingStr = entry.getValue().toString();
            if (checkingStr.contains(key + "=(this Map)") || checkingStr.contains(key + "=(this Collection)"))
                continue;
            this.self.put(key, new Configuration(file, (Map<?, ?>) entry.getValue(), nextDef == this ? null : nextDef)); // prevent infinite loop
        } else {
            this.self.put(key, entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

With `checkingStr.contains(key + "=(this Map)") || checkingStr.contains(key + "=(this Collection)")` I can skip all map to be added into themself.